# jQuery UI Sortable: Drop area is not detected properly if scrolling and connectWith are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

We use jQuery UI Sortable feature to drag & drop the panels between containers. Some containers are empty initially. Sometimes the plugin doesn't detect drop areas properly after container auto-scrolling.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/5mensrec/4/

**Screencast:** http://screencast.com/t/536bYdne

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Scroll the page down a little bit
2. Grab any panel header and move it far down to scroll the page
3. Slowly move mouse up over potential drop areas

**Actual result:** Drop areas are not detected properly until mouse passes some abstract invisible threshold (it is always different). Once it is passed, all drop areas start working.

**Expected result:** Drop areas are detected properly right away.

It is easy to reproduce in Google Chrome. In Firefox, it is challenging but still possible.

Initialization code is very simple:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    handle: ".fe-cd-panel-header",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    connectWith: ".sortable"
});
```

I've left all environment (HTML+CSS) unmodified to give you a full vision of the issue.

Thank you for your help.